# specify preferential subpattern in regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to specify a preferred optional sub pattern but allow for backup. Unfortunately both share part of a pattern, and the preferred match comes after. ex:

```
$string = "Fuzzy bunny is bald";
preg_match_all('@(?:bunny is (\w+)|(\w+) bunny)@',$string,$result);
```

The intended behavior is to ONLY match "bald", unless it cant, in which case it should match "Fuzzy" however because it first encounters a match with "Fuzzy" it does the reverse.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured it out. Have to specify the capturing part of the non-preferring inside the preferred sub pattern, just without capturing it so it can see them at the same time. Then listing them in preferred order works. ex:

'@(?:\w+ bunny is (\w+)|(\w+) bunny)@'

Comment: alternatively, you could prepend the pattern you already have (or both alternatives) with `^.*`. that would be a more general solution and would also work for inputs like `bunny is bald` (without `Fuzzy` there at all).

Comment: To match only alphanumeric characters and disregard if it has numbers in it, you could do. `@(?:[a-zA-Z]+ bunny is ([a-zA-Z]+)|([a-zA-Z]+) bunny)@`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$strings = array("Fuzzy bunny is bald", "Fuzzy bunny is");
$pattern = '~(?J)^(?(?=^[^b]*+bunny is \w++)^[^b]+bunny is (?<word>\w++)|(?<word>\w++) bunny)~';
foreach ($strings as $k => $string) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $match))
        echo "<br/>string$k : " . $match['word'] . "\n";
}
```

or this:

```
$pattern='~(?|(\w++) si ynnub|ynnub (\w++))~';
foreach ($strings as $k => $string) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, strrev($string), $match))
        echo "<br/>string$k : " . strrev($match[1]) . "\n";
}
```